# jetty and slf4j dependencies

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty, jetty-9

I'm using Jetty for a long time. This is the first time I'm getting this error,and I received a lot of this error which made the server not responding well.
I'm using Jetty 9.3.9 only to handle websockets connections.

```
Exception in thread "qtp147268537-19366" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JettyAwareLogger.log(JettyAwareLogger.java:607)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JettyAwareLogger.warn(JettyAwareLogger.java:431)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog.warn(Slf4jLog.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog.warn(Slf4jLog.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:646)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

There were so many errors in a period of 1 hour, that made the server not accepting any new connections, but currently established connections worked well.

After digging more into the problem I think this has to do with this

```
 _logger.log(marker, FQCN, level, msg, null, t);
```

I'm using slf4j-api-1.5.3.jar and slf4j-log4j12-1.5.3.jar. Do I need to upgrade slf4j to a newer version , because it might break some other things in my program? If yes, what is the minimum required version? Or the problem is from something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to upgrade your version of slf4j.

Going to slf4j of at least version 1.6.6 is recommended. (feel free to use something even newer, like version 1.7.12)

The `org.slf4j.api.LocationAware` class was added to support several of the slf4j bridges: jcl-over-slf4j, jul-to-slf4j and log4j-over-slf4j, as well as wrapped loggers.

Jetty's Slf4jLog implementation makes use of wrapped loggers, and as such it needs this class / method to exist.